# SQL: Multiplying two columns(from different tables) and Inserting/Updating(one of the tables)

Tags: t-sql

I have two tables:

`Stock`:

```
ItemID Quantity
111  5.0
222     3.0
```

`Item`:

```
ItemID  Sellper
111     1.0
222     2.0
```

I want to use the `ItemID` to perform `Quantity*Sellper` and the use the result to **update the Quantity field in Stock Table**.

```
SELECT *,Stock.StockQuantity * Item.SellPer As FinaLStockQuantity 
FROM Stock, Item 
WHERE Stock.ItemID = Item.ItemID
```

I can get the results of the product of two columns using the above query but can not get it to update the stock table.

Can someone please help?
P.S: Apologies for the horrible formatting of this post

Comment: You need the `UPDATE` command to update the target table. Have you tried something? Also, do you want to update the `StockQuantity` field or add a new one named `FinalStockQuantity`?

Comment: I would like to update the already existing StockQuantity in the Stock table. I tried the update query but do not exactly know how to write sub queries so getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the [UPDATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx) statement to modify existing data. The documentation has [numerous examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx#OtherTables) on how to update one table from data that comes from other tables.

In your case, assuming there is only one `Item` row per `Stock` row, you can write the following query

```
UPDATE Stock
SET Quantity=Quantity*Item.SellPer
From Stock  s inner join Item i
    on s.ItemID=i.ItemID
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I am getting a "The multi-part identifier "Item.SellPer" could not be bound." error when I try to run the query.

Comment: Thanks got it! :) You are a star!